# Monthly to Daily Value - R

Tags: r, date

I have a data.frame df that has monthly data:

| Company | Store | Brand | Month | Sales | Budget | Quantity | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Store A | Brand A | Jun | $300 | $300 | 3000 | 2022 |
| A | Store A | Brand A | Jul | $300 | $300 | 3000 | 2022 |
| A | Store A | Brand A | Aug | $300 | $300 | 3000 | 2022 |
| A | Store A | Brand A | Sep | $300 | $300 | 3000 | 2022 |

I want there to be the mean value for every day, for example (Jun has 30 days so, Sales $300 / 30 days = $10 per day):

| Company | Store | Brand | Month | Sales | Budget | Quantity | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Store A | Brand A | Jun | $10 | $10 | 100 | 01-06-2022 |
| A | Store A | Brand A | Jun | $10 | $10 | 100 | 02-06-2022 |
| A | Store A | Brand A | Jun | $10 | $10 | 100 | 03-06-2022 |
| A | Store A | Brand A | Jun | $10 | $10 | 100 | 04-06-2022 |
| A | Store A | Brand A | Jun | $10 | $10 | 100 | 05-06-2022 |
| A | Store A | Brand A | Jun | $10 | $10 | 100 | 06-06-2022 |
| A | Store A | Brand A | Jun | $10 | $10 | 100 | 07-06-2022 |

I dont have any idea what function o code could use for that.

Thanks!

Comment: Which language? `Ago` is not a recognisable month. probably you meant `Aug`?

Comment: Yeah! Sorry for that, my main language is Spanish

Comment: @Onyambu, from https://web.library.yale.edu/cataloging/months I'm guessing either Spanish or Portuguese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things up front:

- I'm inferring your locale is set up for Spanish (based on `"Ago"` for what I'm assuming is August). To run this code, I'm first setting up my local locale so that it'll parse correctly. You likely don't need this, but others (in other languages) might need this or similar in order to test this code.

  ```r
  prevlocale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
  Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Spanish")
  # [1] "Spanish_Spain.1252"
  format(as.Date("2022-08-01"), format = "%b")
  # [1] "ago"
  ### when done and you want to return to your local locale
  Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", prevlocale)
  ```
- Your number columns are not numbers. I'll change them to `numeric` since otherwise math ops won't work, you have the option to reformat them into `$`-strings as needed.
- We cannot do this in easy one-step logic for all rows since each month has different numbers of days. To move forward, the first challenge is to determine how many days are in each month. There are several ways to approach this (including the `lubridate` package), I'll offer a base-R solution (using `as.POSIXlt`) to figure it out and return the correct vector of dates.

  ```r
  yrmon2days <- function(yr, mon) {
    stopifnot(length(yr) == 1L, length(mon) == 1L)
    day2 <- day1 <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(paste(yr, mon, "01", sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%b-%d"))
    day2$mon <- day2$mon + 1L
    seq(day1, day2-1, by = "day")
  }
  yrmon2days(2022, "Feb")
  #  [1] "2022-02-01 UTC" "2022-02-02 UTC" "2022-02-03 UTC" "2022-02-04 UTC" "2022-02-05 UTC" "2022-02-06 UTC" "2022-02-07 UTC"
  #  [8] "2022-02-08 UTC" "2022-02-09 UTC" "2022-02-10 UTC" "2022-02-11 UTC" "2022-02-12 UTC" "2022-02-13 UTC" "2022-02-14 UTC"
  # [15] "2022-02-15 UTC" "2022-02-16 UTC" "2022-02-17 UTC" "2022-02-18 UTC" "2022-02-19 UTC" "2022-02-20 UTC" "2022-02-21 UTC"
  # [22] "2022-02-22 UTC" "2022-02-23 UTC" "2022-02-24 UTC" "2022-02-25 UTC" "2022-02-26 UTC" "2022-02-27 UTC" "2022-02-28 UTC"
  ```

  The current is currently not vectorizable; it could be made so, but there are other complications with the surrounding data that made this step a little too far at the moment.
- I tried going down the road of using `dplyr::group_by` and grouping in general, but while it made sense, I didn't want to *assume* one row per year/month. With that precaution, it became clear that we needed a row-wise operation, not something that *might* (though not with this data) return other than 1 row in each group.

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(across(c(Sales, Budget), ~ as.numeric(gsub("\\$", "", .)))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  summarize(
    Date = yrmon2days(Year, Month),
    Company, Store, Brand, Year, Month,
    across(c(where(is.numeric), -Year), ~ . / length(Date))
  )
# # A tibble: 122 x 9
#    Date                Company Store   Brand    Year Month Sales Budget Quantity
#    <dttm>              <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <int> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#  1 2022-06-01 00:00:00 A       Store A Brand A  2022 Jun      10     10      100
#  2 2022-06-02 00:00:00 A       Store A Brand A  2022 Jun      10     10      100
#  3 2022-06-03 00:00:00 A       Store A Brand A  2022 Jun      10     10      100
#  4 2022-06-04 00:00:00 A       Store A Brand A  2022 Jun      10     10      100
#  5 2022-06-05 00:00:00 A       Store A Brand A  2022 Jun      10     10      100
#  6 2022-06-06 00:00:00 A       Store A Brand A  2022 Jun      10     10      100
#  7 2022-06-07 00:00:00 A       Store A Brand A  2022 Jun      10     10      100
#  8 2022-06-08 00:00:00 A       Store A Brand A  2022 Jun      10     10      100
#  9 2022-06-09 00:00:00 A       Store A Brand A  2022 Jun      10     10      100
# 10 2022-06-10 00:00:00 A       Store A Brand A  2022 Jun      10     10      100
# # ... with 112 more rows
```

### base R

```r
dat[c("Sales","Budget")] <- lapply(dat[c("Sales","Budget")], function(z) as.numeric(gsub("\\$", "", z,)))
isnum <- sapply(dat, is.numeric)
isnum[which(colnames(dat) == "Year")] <- FALSE
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)), function(rn) {
  Date <- yrmon2days(dat$Year[rn], dat$Month[rn])
  Nums <- lapply(dat[rn,isnum], `/`, length(Date))
  suppressWarnings( # "row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded"
    cbind(dat[rn,!isnum], Nums, data.frame(Date = Date))
  )
}))
head(out)
#   Company   Store   Brand Month Year Sales Budget Quantity       Date
# 1       A Store A Brand A   Jun 2022    10     10      100 2022-06-01
# 2       A Store A Brand A   Jun 2022    10     10      100 2022-06-02
# 3       A Store A Brand A   Jun 2022    10     10      100 2022-06-03
# 4       A Store A Brand A   Jun 2022    10     10      100 2022-06-04
# 5       A Store A Brand A   Jun 2022    10     10      100 2022-06-05
# 6       A Store A Brand A   Jun 2022    10     10      100 2022-06-06
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Company = c("A", "A", "A", "A"), Store = c("Store A", "Store A", "Store A", "Store A"), Brand = c("Brand A", "Brand A", "Brand A", "Brand A"), Month = c("Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep"), Sales = c("$300", "$300", "$300", "$300"), Budget = c("$300", "$300", "$300", "$300"), Quantity = c(3000L, 3000L, 3000L, 3000L), Year = c(2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: When i use both options (Dplyr and Base) i get this Error: "Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number". I tried with my dataframe and your example data base, i got same error.

Comment: Check to make sure that all of your months are recognized. What does `unique(setdiff(tolower(dat$Month), tolower(format(as.Date(paste(2022, 1:12, 1, sep="-")), format = "%b"))))` return?